# Vetor de objetos em Python

Tags: python

Desejo criar uma classe Nodo, e um de seus atributos é um vetor de Nodos (como em uma lista encadeada). Como em Python não se declara o tipo do atributo, não tenho idéia dd como fazer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numa lista encadeada normal cada nó tem um atributo que representa o próximo nó apenas e não uma lista:

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
        self.prox = None
```

Se no seu caso particular precisa de ter um atributo que é uma lista para os vários nós pode fazer assim:

```
class Nodo:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
        self.nodos = [] #lista de Nodos
```

Agora nessa lista irá adicionar cada `Nodo` à medida que precisa utilizando por exemplo a função `append`:

```
self.nodos.append(Nodo(10))
```

Em Python não se declara o tipo do atributo, mas o tipo é construído consoante o seu valor. Isto significa que se quer ter uma lista de elementos de um determinado tipo, necessita apenas de adicionar à lista elementos desse tipo.

Comment: Obrigado, foi muito útil. nesse caso como faço para verificar se uma posição da lista esta vazia?

Comment: @LeonardoFurtado De nada. Não funciona propriamente dessa maneira. Ao remover um determinado nó da lista é como se todos os outros andassem uma posição para trás de forma a ocupar o espaço deixado. Logo a lista na verdade nunca tem buracos.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado.